# wpf break IsVisibleChangedEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, .net-4.6

I have my usercontrol that has the `IsVisibleChanged` method.. that is fired when become visibile or when hide..

I wish, in some conditions break this event to avoid the hide set.... how can I do this?

the event is this:

```cs
private void MetroContentControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
    {
        // goes visible
    }
    else
    {
        // hide it!
        if (myCondition == true)
        {
            // here I wish break the hide event and mantain the user control visible
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: set e.handled to true

Comment: I haven't the e.handled property
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencypropertychangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: If you want to avoid that the control becomes hidden, why do you hide it in the first place? There is nothing you can do about this in the event handler that is being invoked in reponse to the control being hidden or collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do, should be done before the `Visibility` property is changed. The event `IsVisibleChanged` will be triggered after the `Visibility` is changed. So handling it will not help.

If you're using MVVM, I would suggest you to use `IValueConverter` to handle this kind of scenario. Using `Style.Triggers` is also one more option.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, try to use a flag and assign it as true inside your condition and then put your whole code inside the checking of this flag.
For eg:

```
private bool isBreaked=false;

private void MetroContentControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!isBreaked)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
        {
          // goes visible
        }
        else
        {
          // hide it!
          if (myCondition == true)
          {
            // here I wish break the hide event and mantain the user control visible
            isBreaked = true;
          }
        }
    }
}
```